# sell stocks of liquidated indian company

Tags: bse-india, liquidation

I have stocks in Bellary Steel and Alloys that I got from my parents. When I checked the company, looks like it was liquidated. Is there anyway I can sell these shares or get money from them ?

Comment: Can you put some time frame on these events? Something that was liquidated last month is different than something that happened 30 years ago.

Comment: My dad mustve bought these before the '08 crash. Based on what I have searched, it stopped trading in Feb 2011. I got these stocks transferred to me in 2019.